# Pronunciation of часá (часы, часов)

Tags: перевод, произношение

My Russian teacher, claims that when pronouncing "часá" it should be pronounced as: "чi-сa" with an "i" instead of an "a". I have looked around and it appears that the pronunciation hinges around: "cha-sa". You are native Russian speakers and could perhaps tell me what is correct and what is a myth.

- http://www.dummies.com/how-to/content/how-to-tell-time-in-russian.html
- http://masterrussian.com/httelltime.shtml

Comment: That depends on stress. Unstressed vowel (as in полчасá) is reduced, stressed one (as in и чáса не прошло) not.

Comment: Большое спасибо.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Your teacher is absolutely right. According to the rules of pronunciation of the Russian unstressed vowels,

> the letter `a` after `ч` and `щ` in an unstressed syllable is
>   pronounced as the letter `и`, that is as [ɪ].

Have a look:

> [часы́](https://en.wiktionary.org/wiki/%D1%87%D0%B0%D1%81%D1%8B)  - [t͡ɕɪˈsɨ] 'clock'
>
> [часовóй](https://en.wiktionary.org/wiki/%D1%87%D0%B0%D1%81%D0%BE%D0%B2%D0%BE%D0%B9) - [t͡ɕɪsɐˈvoj] 'sentry'
>
> [щавéль](https://en.wiktionary.org/wiki/%D1%89%D0%B0%D0%B2%D0%B5%D0%BB%D1%8C) - [ɕːɪˈvʲelʲ] 'sorrel, dock (plant)'
>
> [счастли́вый](https://en.wiktionary.org/wiki/%D1%81%D1%87%D0%B0%D1%81%D1%82%D0%BB%D0%B8%D0%B2%D1%8B%D0%B9) - [ɕːɪˈslʲivɨj] 'happy'

That is why the word `часá` is pronounced as [t͡ɕɪˈsa].

Comment: So a majority of the references out there are completely obsolete including my "russian textbook".

Comment: Совершенно верно. Можно послушать машинный голосовой синтез https://translate.yandex.ru/?text=%D0%94%D0%B8%D0%BA%D1%82%D0%BE%D1%80%20%D1%81%D0%B5%D0%B3%D0%BE%D0%B4%D0%BD%D1%8F%20%D0%BF%D1%80%D0%BE%D1%87%D0%B8%D1%82%D0%B0%D0%BB%20%D1%81%D0%BB%D0%BE%D0%B2%D0%BE%20%D1%87%D0%B0%D1%81%D1%8B%20%D0%B8%20%D0%B7%D0%B0%D1%82%D0%B5%D0%BC%20%D1%81%D0%BB%D0%BE%D0%B2%D0%BE%20%D0%B4%D1%8F%D0%B4%D1%8F.&lang=ru-en Синтез, как известно, составляется статистически, но основе анализа большого массива непроизвольной речи. По этой же причине, непроизвольности-нарочитости, сайты типа *Forvo* это зло.

Comment: Большой спасибо!

Comment: @Ana: please mark the right answer, if you consider there is one.

Comment: Your teacher seems to be right, but it depends on the "dialect". Some people articulate this as "a", some - close to "i". But never-never try to pronnounce a clear "i". It's something average between "a" and "i". I am an urban native speaker.

Comment: @Avtokod honestly the speaker following the link reads it more like [а] than [и].

Comment: I think the teacher is from a place with a dialect that is more leaning towards the "i" than the "a". I ran a few speech machines and the pronounciations lean more toward an "a" than an "i". The only word that is more "i" than "a" is the "clock" word --> часы́ - [t͡ɕɪˈsɨ] 'clock' in the час-related words. I think it is a little funny because she never corrects anyone on incorrect pronounciation so I have to count on machines and questions here. I have many times tested my guess by totally screwing up the pronounciation on purpose to see if she reacts and corrects it. But she does not. :-D

Comment: @Ana it is not that the teacher from some dialect area. It is that the teachers are taught to use this way of instruction. When I was learning English I also was taught by teachers a lot or wrong stuff. I personally would distinguish чисы from часы in speach and never pronounce it as чисы either. It is even more likely that I would pronounce it as "чесы".

Comment: I think it is a pity in these modern times that you replicate things that are imperfect and propagate them instead of correcting them and making sure all students no matter what language can get it right on their first try. I think if someone detects something that is not 100% and corrects that person is in my book someone with intellect, engagement and interest but if you became a teacher just to land a job and care less about your students then you get a situation when students have to spend more time on minor things instead of focusing on the challenging things.

Comment: Meaning that you learn less that you could have but I guess this phenomenon is not unique in my part of the world. Knowledge appears to become diluted when letting in people that have no interest or have skills in teaching. I am happy that I by accident run across this site. You guys have helped me alot, with invaluable insights and thoughts. For this I am very happy. Я очень радa.

Comment: @Anixx , да, об оттенках услышанного можно спорить )) Вот еще произношение: http://ru.speaklanguages.com/%D1%80%D1%83%D1%81%D1%81%D0%BA%D0%B8%D0%B9/%D1%84%D1%80%D0%B0%D0%B7%D1%8B/%D0%B2%D1%8B%D1%80%D0%B0%D0%B6%D0%B5%D0%BD%D0%B8%D1%8F-%D0%B2%D1%80%D0%B5%D0%BC%D0%B5%D0%BD%D0%B8 Вот пара "Чистота / частота" https://translate.yandex.ru/?text=%D0%A7%D0%B8%D1%81%D1%82%D0%BE%D1%82%D0%B0%20%D0%BD%D0%B5%20%D1%81%D0%BB%D1%8B%D1%88%D0%BD%D0%B0%20%D0%B2%20%D1%87%D0%B0%D1%81%D1%82%D0%BE%D1%82%D0%B5%20%D0%B7%D0%B2%D1%83%D0%BA%D0%BE%D0%B2&lang=ru-en

Comment: @Ana : Фраза __"Диктор сегодня прочитал слово часы и затем слово дядя"__ была составлена специально. Слово *сегодня* произносится "сиводня", в слове *дядя* слышится лёгкое "дзядзя" )) Но последнее как раз не приветствуется, по крайней мере это известный театральный тест. Если *часы* сказано чАсы, а *дядя* как дзядзя, то человека уже не переучишь, слишком много ошибок ))))))

Comment: @Ana  By the way, there are two words differing only in unstressed и/е, чистота "cleanness" and частота "frequency". These words are pronounced differently and no native speaker would ever confuse them. https://translate.yandex.ru/?text=%D0%A0%D0%B0%D0%B7%D0%BB%D0%B8%D1%87%D0%B8%D0%B5%20%D0%B7%D0%B2%D1%83%D0%BA%D0%BE%D0%B2%20%D0%B2%20%D1%87%D0%B8%D1%81%D1%82%D0%BE%D1%82%D0%B5%20%D0%B8%D0%BB%D0%B8%20%D0%B2%20%D1%87%D0%B0%D1%81%D1%82%D0%BE%D1%82%D0%B5%20%D0%BE%D1%87%D0%B5%D0%BD%D1%8C%20%D0%B2%D0%B0%D0%B6%D0%BD%D0%BE.&lang=ru-en

Comment: I have marked the answer. Sorry for being slow. I was not fully aware of how it works. Thanks for sharing and your patience.

Answer (score 5):

Do not think of a vowel reduction as simply a vowel "replace". Honestly, every time when I see a phonetic transcription, I can't believe that it's the same what I speak.

Actually, the rule of reduction is really simple: speak neither `чi-са`, nor `ча-са`, nor `че-са`, but `ч-са`, where the dash stands for "some noise" left between spelling `ч` and `с`. No speaker really cares if it's closer to one vowel or another. Just do it quick and never stress.

Comment: «[Иканье](https://ru.wikipedia.org/wiki/%D0%98%D0%BA%D0%B0%D0%BD%D1%8C%D0%B5) … в настоящее время является орфоэпической нормой русского литературного языка наряду с допустимым еканьем».

Comment: @YellowSky Норма нормой, а живой язык - это живой язык. Все мы периодически и "екаем", и "окаем". Человек же просто изучает русский язык как иностранный, а не готовится работать диктором на телевидении.

Comment: То есть, вы хотите сказать, что, изучая язык как иностранный, не нужно учить его норму?

Comment: @YellowSky Я думаю, что нормы бывают разные. А в том, что касается произношения, излишняя близость к норме вообще вредна - будешь выглядеть или как советский диктор, или как американский шпион :-)

Comment: То, что вы говорите, это то же самое, как если бы американец советовал русскому не учиться говорить «going to», «want to» и «let me», а настаивал бы на том, что все говорят «gonna», «wanna» и «lemme», и так и нужно говорить, а если говорить по норме, то его за ненормального будут принимать. На самом деле всё зависит от приоритетов: если человек собирается общаться только с гопотой, то ему, естественно, норму знать не надо, но если человек собирается общаться с по-настоящему образованными людьми, то именно норму ему изучать и следует.

Comment: @YellowSky Ну Вы уж не путайте тёплое с мягким. "шОфер" - это, положим, жаргон, а "чЕсы" - это всего лишь особенность произношения.

Comment: Я ничего не путаю, в своём первом комментарии я же привёл цитату о том, что еканье допустимо.

Comment: @YellowSky Ну так значит "часы" через "а", по-Вашему, выходит не допустимо? Это ж не еканье.

Comment: Допустимо, но только при утрированно чётком, раздельном произношении, повторяющем правописание.

Comment: @Yellow Sky это в каком справочнике такое уточнение делается или вы сами сочинили?

Answer (score 0):

As a native speaker, I can assure you it definitely is pronounced as "cha-sa". And I really can't pinpoint the myth origin.

Update:

Considering that a in ча can be both stressed and unstressed, it really is pronounced differently depending on stress. But it's still is pronounced as a, not as I. It's just less opened and bright.

Comment: You can't assure me - I've been studying Russian for four years and I have yet to hear anyone say cha-sá. I've only ever heard chi-sá, chi-sóv, etc.

Comment: @CocoPop this synthesizer speaks a and it sounds totally correct. https://translate.yandex.ru/?text=%D0%94%D0%B8%D0%BA%D1%82%D0%BE%D1%80%20%D1%81%D0%B5%D0%B3%D0%BE%D0%B4%D0%BD%D1%8F%20%D0%BF%D1%80%D0%BE%D1%87%D0%B8%D1%82%D0%B0%D0%BB%20%D1%81%D0%BB%D0%BE%D0%B2%D0%BE%20%D1%87%D0%B0%D1%81%D1%8B%20%D0%B8%20%D0%B7%D0%B0%D1%82%D0%B5%D0%BC%20%D1%81%D0%BB%D0%BE%D0%B2%D0%BE%20%D0%B4%D1%8F%D0%B4%D1%8F.&lang=ru-en

Comment: I can second that one. The yandex must be used by a lot of russians/russian speaking users so it has a much better selection of words and pronounciations. There are only a few minor words that I run into that are not fully pronounced but the yandex one is the best so far. I have used many others and they are a total disaster compared to yandex. I also got the impression that the yandex is much "cleaner" pronounciation.

Comment: I personally think that @user4419802 has the most accurate answer.

Comment: @Anixx - Your synthesizer says [t͡ɕɪˈsɨ], and that's totally correct.

Comment: @CocoPop also this one shows the difference https://translate.yandex.ru/?text=%D0%A0%D0%B0%D0%B7%D0%BB%D0%B8%D1%87%D0%B8%D0%B5%20%D0%B7%D0%B2%D1%83%D0%BA%D0%BE%D0%B2%20%D0%B2%20%D1%87%D0%B8%D1%81%D1%82%D0%BE%D1%82%D0%B5%20%D0%B8%D0%BB%D0%B8%20%D0%B2%20%D1%87%D0%B0%D1%81%D1%82%D0%BE%D1%82%D0%B5%20%D0%BE%D1%87%D0%B5%D0%BD%D1%8C%20%D0%B2%D0%B0%D0%B6%D0%BD%D0%BE.&lang=ru-en

Comment: @Anixx: Sorry, I listened to both of them and they both had the syllable че- and not ча-. In the second one, they both sound to me like чистоте́. No difference.

Comment: Actually, the woman on the Yandex synthesizer speaks too fast and robotic. Listen to Dmitry on Oddcast say your text - you can also adjust the speed. There are also four other female voices, but they're more robotic: http://www.oddcast.com/demos/tts/tts_example.php?clients

Comment: @CocoPop Dmitry pronounces wrong stress in звуков, but otherwise I hear him pronouncing чистоте and частоте differently. Чистоте he pronounces with a very short vowel, non-real I would say. частоте he pronounces with what I perceive as clear а.

Comment: @CocoPop Milena on the other hand seems to pronounce in both cases и. As a native speaker I would say that I perceive the whole phrase as having repeated word чистоте. That is the meaning is lost.